# Issue with output of java program involving string

Tags: java

```
class Blue_ManTest{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String name = "I LOVE JAVAWORLD";
        int index1 = name.indexOf(" ");
        int index2 = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
        String str1 = name.substring(0, index1);
        String str2 = name.substring(index1 + 1, index1+ 5);
        String str3 = name.substring(index2 + 5);
        System.out.println(str3 + ", " + str1 + " " + str2 + ".");
    }
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out what would be the output of this program I think I know it but I am not sure.

I did this I Love JavaWorld with 0 corresponding to j and 15 to D with 1 being the space between.

for `str1` I get `I`

for `str2` I get `Love`

but for `str3` I get `avaWorld`

But `str3` seems wrong to me as it would print out.

```
avaWorld, I  Love.
```

Comment: Why dont you just run it?

Comment: I ran it and got `WORLD, I LOVE.`

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: String 3 is confusing me how does it work because it starts index 2 which is L plus 5 which is 7 and give you J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `str3` variable is taking a substring that starts at `index2 + 5` where `index2` is the index of the *last* space in your input string:

```
int index2 = name.lastIndexOf(" ");
```

That is, `index2` is 6. And of course 6 + 5 is 11.

Comment: and index 2 is that not L in I LOVE JAVAWORLD ?

Comment: Yes I think what confused me is that  index1 = name.indexOf(" "); the quotation marks mean blank because they have nothing inside.

Comment: The quotation marks don't have nothing inside, they have a single space character.